# Pre-filled user info in Django Comments?

Tags: django, django-views

The site I'm building uses the standard user management framework and 
the standard comments framework.

What I'd like to see happen is the comments form rendered with the 
user's name and email address pre-filled if they are already signed in 
(or have the fields hidden entirely - kinda like theregister's comments system!).

Easy enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use django-comments with logged-in users, the `post_comment` does already populate some fields right when being authenticated, you just need to make some tweaks. There are [some instructions](http://www.yashh.com/blog/2008/nov/21/django-comments-authenticated-users/) on how to do that!

Answer (score 0):

If user are signed in, you can use something like this in your view:

```
 user = request.user
 profile = user.get_profile()
 if request.method == 'POST':
       edit_form = YourForm(data = request.POST, user = user)
       if edit_form.is_valid():
            ...
 else:
       dict = {'email':user.email, 'username':user.username}
       form = YourForm(user = user, data = dict)
       tpl_dict = {'form' : form,}
       return render_to_response('template.html', tpl_dict)
```

it will fill the form fields 'username' and 'email'

Answer (score 0):

When I'm signed into my django site it automatically loads my username and email address.